# Undeterministic C Behavior?"Fork bomb"

Tags: c, fork, kill

So I created a "fork" bomb per say. However when I run it on my computer it kills everything on my computer, goes to black screen then restores itself.

On my friends computer when running the same exact code, his actually does a fork bomb but never makes it to the kill loop.

Any reason why?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){

    int pc = 0;
    int* pids = calloc(1025,sizeof(int));
    L1:
        while(1){
            int pid = fork();
            if(pid != 0)
            {
                pc++;
                pids[pc] = pid;

            }

            if(pc == 1024)
            {
                goto L2;
                break;
            }
        }
    L2:
        while(1){
            if(pids[pc] != 0) {
                kill(pids[pc],SIGKILL);
            }

            if(pc == 0)
            {
                goto L1;
                break;
            }

            pc--;
        }
    free(pids);
}
```

Note this code is just for funsies.

Update:

putting pc++. outside of the if statement caused a kernel panic. Could someone explain to me why?

In theory this code doesn't even work.

Comment: Does `ulimit -u` report the same values?

Comment: my ulimit is actually pretty small so this might be the issue?

Comment: @DaBler do you know how to change the ulimit -u in Mac OS Sierra? I can't seem to find anywhere on how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're probably crashing is that it's possible for `fork()` to fail, in which case it will return -1. When you call `kill(-1, SIGKILL)`, it sends `SIGKILL` to *every process on your system*. If you're running as a privileged user, the reason this is terrible should be obvious.

Side notes:

1. The return type of `fork()` is `pid_t`, *not* `int`. In most cases, `pid_t` happens to fit in an `int`, but you should use the proper types.
2. It's pointless to have a `break` statement after a `goto` statement. The `break` can never be reached.
3. If you enabled warnings on your compiler, it probably would have told you about both of those.

Answer (score 1):

["fork bomb"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), by its nature, can't have any deterministic behaviour. In theory, a computer with infinite resources can keep on forking without any problem.
But in practice, we know computers don't have infinite resources. So, different operating systems might handle the resource drain in different ways.

Typically, when the operating system can't spawn further processes, the kernel might kill the "offending" process(es) in order to free up resources or crash or get into a limbo state. The exponential growth of processes is generally hard to handle for the kernel even if it recognizes it.

So, you just can't expect anything deterministic or repeatable behaviour.

Comment: My friend and I have the same computer model everything. His loads the processes(keeping track with top). However mine just goes and kills everything I'm assuming. I just don't understand why mine goes and kills and his doesn't and its because the computers are different, so in some way, the same thing is getting handled differently?

Comment: Even the *same* OS can behave/handle it differently when you try the next time. There's no "expected" behaviour when an OS is about crash.